# Adding military time to date returns error: 'int' object is unsliceable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm unable to add Military Time to my datetime64[ns].

df.head(3):

```
    year    day military_time   date    test
0   2018    1   5   2018-01-01  20180010005
1   2018    1   10  2018-01-01  20180010010
2   2018    1   15  2018-01-01  20180010015
```

df.dtypes:

```
day                                 int64
military_time                       int64
year                                int64
date                       datetime64[ns]
test                                int64
dtype: object
```

I'm parsing the data from text files. I managed to create **date** based on **year** and **day** of the year columns.

```
tmp['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tmp['year'] * 1000 + tmp['day'], format='%Y%j')
```

I wanted to add new column **date2** by adding military time to **date** using same approach:

```
tmp['date2'] = pd.to_datetime((tmp['year'] * 1000 + tmp['day'])*10000 + tmp['military_time'], format='%Y%j%H%M')
```

But go an error like below.

Traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-001f7c6aee03> in <module>()
     14     tmp['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tmp['year'] * 1000 + tmp['day'], format='%Y%j')
     15     tmp['test'] = (tmp['year'] * 1000 + tmp['day'])*10000 + tmp['military_time']
---> 16     tmp['date2'] = pd.to_datetime((tmp['year'] * 1000 + tmp['day'])*10000 + tmp['military_time'], format='%Y%j%H%M')
     17     #tmp['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(tmp['test'],format='%Y%j%H%M')
     18     #tmp['test2'] = zfill(tmp['test'],10)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    449         else:
    450             from pandas import Series
--> 451             values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
    452             result = Series(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    453     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, MutableMapping)):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name, tz)
    345                     try:
    346                         result = array_strptime(arg, format, exact=exact,
--> 347                                                 errors=errors)
    348                     except tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime:
    349                         if errors == 'raise':

pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

TypeError: 'int' object is unsliceable
```

Comment: what exactly is 'military time', how does it look like?

Comment: It's an integer, sample values: 5, 55, 2235, which mean: 00:05, 00:55, 22:35. It's a military notation for timestamp with 24H notation. https://militaryconnection.com/military-time/

Comment: Ok, allow me the question: why re-invent the wheel? There's the default datetime object https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects and you could simply implement a custom output for it? What exactly is your input and your output?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how could I do that given the current dataset?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I have no error with your code.

Comment: My sample inputs are contained within the columns: year, day and military time. Considering the following sample values: year (2018), day of the year (32) and military time (5), I would like to output the datetime column looking like this: 2018-02-01 00:05:00.

Comment: @saif3r Using `df = pd.DataFrame({'year': {0: 2018, 1: 2018, 2: 2018}, 'day': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1}, 'military_time': {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 15}})` followed by `df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime((df['year'] * 1000 + df['day'])*10000 + df['military_time'], format='%Y%j%H%M')` is working, not for you ?

Comment: As it turned out, I had rows with '2400' in my military_time column, which caused above function to fail. `df['military_time'].replace({2400: 0}, inplace=True)` did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://militaryconnection.com/military-time/), Military Time notation can contain 0000 or 2400 as Midnight indication. The data set I was using, had 2400, that's why `pd.to_datetime` was unable to parse my time properly. I replaced it using `tmp['military_time'].replace({2400: 0}, inplace=True)` and then I was able to parse it to time properly using `tmp['date2'] = pd.to_datetime((tmp['year'] * 1000 + tmp['day'])*10000 + tmp['military_time'], format='%Y%j%H%M')`